Drawing a circle where each arc connecting three consecutive nodes is of a different color than the next arc
I want to draw a circle where each arc connecting three consecutive nodes is of a different color than the next arc. Each new arc should start from the last node of the previous arc and continue to the next two consecutive nodes, thus alternating the colors between the arcs.
My attempted code is provided below, but certainly it requires some tweaks to achieve the desired output. Currently, it does not produce arcs of different colors. Do you have any other suggestions for improving the graph, possibly using any built-in libraries?
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\numnodes{4} % Define the number of nodes
  \def\radius{4cm} % Define the radius of the circle

  % Define the coordinates of the nodes in a circular layout
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\numnodes} {
    \node (\i) at ({360/\numnodes * (\i - 1)}:\radius) {\i};
  }

  % Draw the edges in sequences of three nodes with alternating colors
  \foreach \i in {1,3,...,\numnodes} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\second}{mod(\i,\numnodes) + 1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\third}{mod(\i+1,\numnodes) + 1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\fourth}{mod(\i+2,\numnodes) + 1}

    \ifodd\i
      \draw [red, thick, ->] (\i) -- (\second);
      \draw [red, thick, ->] (\second) -- (\third);
      \draw [red, thick, ->] (\third) -- (\fourth);
    \else
      \draw [blue, thick, ->] (\i) -- (\second);
      \draw [blue, thick, ->] (\second) -- (\third);
      \draw [blue, thick, ->] (\third) -- (\fourth);
    \fi
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Test parity of \i/2 instead of \i and draw just two segments (to link three nodes):
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\numnodes{16} % Define the number of nodes
  \def\radius{4cm} % Define the radius of the circle

  % Define the coordinates of the nodes in a circular layout
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\numnodes} {
    \node (\i) at ({360/\numnodes * (\i - 1)}:\radius) {\i};
  }

  % Draw the edges in sequences of three nodes with alternating colors
  \foreach \i in {1,3,...,\numnodes} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\second}{mod(\i,\numnodes) + 1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\third}{mod(\i+1,\numnodes) + 1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ibis}{mod(\i/2,2)}

    \ifodd\ibis
      \draw [red, thick, ->] (\i) -- (\second);
      \draw [red, thick, ->] (\second) -- (\third);
    \else
      \draw [blue, thick, ->] (\i) -- (\second);
      \draw [blue, thick, ->] (\second) -- (\third);
    \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks @PaulGaborit for very useful answer. Two observations: (1). For 6, 10, 14, ..., might be appropriate to introduce an other color, like green. (2). Would appreciate it if you provide the lead to display numbers with circles surrounding the numbers.

@MYaseen208 Do not change the rules during competition ! :-)
